# npm says port is allready in even if you change the port

Tags: reactjs, npm, jetbrains-ide, hyper-v

Recently I have started to use React Native and I didn't want to use Android Studio, so I manually installed every thing including `hyper-v` but after that I have a really strange problem if I put any port in `.env` file when I run `npm start` it saying that the port is in use!

And the other issue was when I was using JetBrains' products (like WebStorm) it won't start. I found this in log files :

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

And the most strange thing was that the ports were not in use !

So after a week I found the solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple this is a problem with `hyper-v` and `wsl2`, and I don't know why it cause this problem.

I solved my problem using two commands (I'm using Windows 10) :

```
net stop winnat

net start winnat
```

I hope this fix your issue!

Edit:
Even after you reset the reserved ports by the command, after a full restart then you will need to run the command again.
This is because of `windows sandbox`. It'll re-reserve the ports.
So to fully fix the problem you need to turn off `windows sandbox` in `windows features`, that will fully fix the problem